# How to include jquery plugin (HTML) into JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am confused about one thing. I want to use jQuery plugin, but I want to active it in my JS function. 
So  in my JS i want to add the code of plugin:

JS

```
var kontaktOffset = $('.kontakt').offset().top + 100;

if (wScroll > kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 1.05)) {

    $('.eboy').css("display", "none");
}
```

But instead display: none I want this HTML and CSS code :

```
<div class="scrollme">
<div class="effect_box effect_box_translate animateme"
    data-translatey="500"
    data-translatex="-650"
    data-to="0.85" 
    data-from="0.45"
    data-when="view" 
    style="opacity: 1; 
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
    rotateX(0deg) 
    rotateY(0deg)   
    rotateZ(0deg) 
    scale3d(1, 1, 1);">
<img src ="images/eboy.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" width="auto" height="300" style="padding-top:50px">
</div>
</div>
```

SO can someone help me how to include this plugin code into my JS? 
And I hope to this is properly question.

Comment: You want _all_ of that html and css placed _inside_ the _if_ statement, or do you want to place _that_ css inside of the `$('.eboy').css(); `?

Comment: @AngelofDemons I want to place it inside of the **$('.eboy').css()/html()...

Comment: You cant place html in the _css_ property (atleast I think so?) You CAN however place a _html_ property like this: `$('.eboy').html()` and then place the css in the `$('.eboy').css()` OR you can just place the html inside the if statement and the css in your `.css` file with the correct names given to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```js
var eboy = $('.eboy').addClass('scrollme');
ebody.append('<div class="effect_box effect_box_translate animateme"'+
    'data-translatey="500"'+
    'data-translatex="-650"'+
    'data-to="0.85" '+
    'data-from="0.45"'+
    'data-when="view" '+
    'style="opacity: 1;'+ 
    'transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)'+
    'rotateX(0deg) '+
    'rotateY(0deg) '+
    'rotateZ(0deg) '+
    'scale3d(1, 1, 1);">'+
'<img src ="images/eboy.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" width="auto" height="300" style="padding-top:50px">'+
'</div>');
```

Comment: It does not working, but it seems like a good direction. Thank you, all advice are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if (wScroll > kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 1.05)) {

    $('.eboy').html('<div class="scrollme">
<div class="effect_box effect_box_translate animateme"
    data-translatey="500"
    data-translatex="-650"
    data-to="0.85" 
    data-from="0.45"
    data-when="view" 
    style="opacity: 1; 
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
    rotateX(0deg) 
    rotateY(0deg)   
    rotateZ(0deg) 
    scale3d(1, 1, 1);">
<img src ="images/eboy.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" width="auto" height="300" style="padding-top:50px">
</div>
</div>');
}
```